# Need to find the Id which has different details in the detail table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my table cash_main:

"CASH_MAIN" table has TWO columns as shown below:

```
CASHID   Amount
7          1000
9          300
```

The Deatils  will be in "cash_detail" table:

```
cash_detailid cashID     agentid   Amount
 1             7          101       200
 2             7          102       200
 3             7          103       200
 4             7          104       200
 5             7          105       200
 6             9          106       300
```

I am trying to get the cashid  which has multiple agentid's linked in the detail table :

```
cashid     
7
```

Here in the example cashid:7 has multiple agent id's which totals to 1000
but we shouldn't pick cashid:9 as it has only one single agentid and that has 300

I am trying to use this below query but it is not fetching me correct result:

```
WITH Duplicateaccounts
AS (
    SELECT CASHID 
        ,count(*) AS rcount
    FROM cash_detail 
    GROUP BY CASHID 
    HAVING count(*) > 1
    )
SELECT CASHID 
 FROM cash_detail  a
JOIN cash_MAIN b ON b.CASHID = a.CASHID 
ORDER BY a.cashid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select cd.cashID
from cash_detail cd
group by cd.cashID
having min(agentid) <> max(agentid);
```

Comment: Gordon, I've seen you and others giving this kind of answer many time and it always makes me wonder, why you always use `<>`? I mean is `<` not enough? Of course at the end of the day, there is no difference in results or performance between `<>` and `<`, but it's just a matter of code beauty :). I mean is it not silly to expect `MIN() > MAX()`? I know that all of you who use `<>` mean to say when they're not equal, which is the logic that the query tries to achieve, but then once written, it just feels silly :). Or perhaps I'm just too lazy to type or read one more unnecessary character :).

Comment: @RacilHilan . . . That is interesting.  In my case, it is just in case I type `max()` first.

Comment: Oh, that's wired in my hands nerves, so they will automatically switch it to `>`, no brain involved :P (just kidding of course).

Answer (score 0):

COUNT(DISTINCT) can be used to identify where there are different values in a particular field.

```
SELECT cash_detail.cashID
FROM cash_detail 
GROUP BY cash_detail.cashID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cash_detail.agentid)>1;
```